# Strange issue with offset top in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Usually I can figure these things out, but based on what I can see it seems that this code is off by roughly 700 pixels of the actual offset.

What I am doing here is basically locking a button just under a fixed header when you scroll past it. Testing the console output i can see that the button is about 713 pixels from the top according to this code. However it is actually about 1300 pixels from the top. 713 pixels references roughly in the middle of another element, so logically its impossible for me to get that number.

Here is my code.

```
    window.contOffset = jQuery('#cont-step3').offset();
    window.contWidth = jQuery('#cont-step3').outerWidth();
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if(window.contOffset.top<jQuery(document).scrollTop()){
            jQuery('#cont-step3').css({
                position:'fixed',
                top:'70px',
                left:window.contOffset.left+'px',
                width:window.contWidth+'px'
            });
        }else{
            jQuery('#cont-step3').removeAttr('style');
        }
        console.log(window.contOffset,jQuery(document).scrollTop());
    });
    jQuery('#core-values2').sortable({
        update:function(event,ui){
            updateValues();
        }
    });
```

The problem may just not be jumping out to me, my logic in this code is that when the user scrolls past the element (roughly 1300 pixels, but the site is responsive so I have to calculate it). It will add an inline style to the element giving it a fixed position. When the user scrolls back up it removes it. Very simple concept and not a lot of code needed, this issue has stumped me though and for a script that takes at most 5 minuts I have already spent 2 hours debugging.

Has anyone else run into this? Am I just totally missing something? I have used a similar method before with no problems.

I am using jQuery 1.10.2

work in progress fiddle
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/HFapE/)
The jsfiddle does not scroll/allow it so this example might need something more to even attempt to test.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I am not sure, there may be a connection to the full website code in the calculation (borders of other elements, margins ect). So in the case a jsfiddle might not see the same problem. I will however put the code together and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not just checking on dom completion but reinitialize the event with EVERY change in the dom, any other javascript that may change a property (like a menu) throws off the scroll event.

I managed to hook up the function to remove then reinitialize the event every time there is a change to anything and that worked.

```
jQuery(window).off('scroll').on('scroll',function(){
        if(window.contOffset.top<jQuery(document).scrollTop()){
            jQuery('#cont-step3').css({
                position:'fixed',
                top:'70px',
                left:window.contOffset.left+'px',
                width:window.contWidth+'px'
            });
        }else{
            jQuery('#cont-step3').removeAttr('style');
        }
        console.log(window.contOffset,jQuery(document).scrollTop());
    });
```